# Get link in Symfony2 functional tests

Tags: testing, symfony, hyperlink

I have an issue with Symfony2 functional tests.

I have used the code described in the documentation (http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/testing.html#functional-tests)

The following code example is my test. I want to check if I am on the right page (by testing if a link exists) and then, I want to click on this link to go to another page.

I do not understand why the first test works perfectly (check if the link exists) and why the second test fails (click on the same link).

I have this exception "InvalidArgumentException: The current node list is empty." on the line marked by "THIS DOES NOT WORK" below.

Maybe I made a typo in the syntax but I've checked with the documentation many times and everything looks ok.

Any idea? Here is my code

```
public function testConnexion()
{

    $client = static::createClient();

    // get the index page. As we are not logged in, we are redirected ...
    $client->request('GET', '/');

    $crawler = $client->followRedirect();

    // ... to the welcome page
    $this->assertGreaterThan(
        0,
        $crawler->filter('#connexion a.bluebtn')->count() // THIS WORKS
    );


    // We click on "get access" link ...
    $link = $crawler->filter('#connexion a.bluebtn')->eq(1)->link(); // THIS DOES NOT WORK
    $crawler = $client->click($link);

   // other tests...
```

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried what is suggested in the documentation http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/testing.html#links ?

Comment: mmmm. No... And it works like that. If you have an explanation, I would like to know it. Else I'll have a look to the selectLink() method to see what are the differences with my code above.
By the way, thank you :)